# Declaration and entity denoted by this name

Tags: c++

Declaration is introduced one or more name into translation unit. This name denote a specifiec entity. But what is occuring if we just declare, but not define a name? Example:

```
extern int a;//Declaration, not definition. What is the entity denoted by a?
a=6;//Now a denote the enitity which has value equals to 6
```

Comment: Do you mean there is no other global `int a` in the project? Might be an error in that case no?

Comment: Yes, there is no global int a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in 3/3:

> A name is a use of an identifier (2.11), operator-function-id(13.5),
>   literal-operator-id(13.5.8), conversion-function-id(12.3.2), or
>   template-id(14.2) **that denotes an entity** or label (6.6.4,6.1).

This implies that every name denote some entity by definition. In your case the value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It will not compile. As it is declared `external`, but no entity is declared in any other compilation unit, **the linker** will throw an `unresolved external` error. (the `object` will actually compile, but it won't be able to be linked in an executable).